# JMeter - Add Custom HTTP Headers Programatically in HTTPSampler

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am addding custom headers to HTTPSampler programmatically while setting up JMeter test plan.

Please refer below snippet for the same:

```
HeaderManager headerManager = new HeaderManager();
headerManager.add(new Header("Foo", "Joe"));
sampler.setHeaderManager(headerManager);`
```

The problem here is that this custom header is not being sent to server.

Is there anything that I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

It won't work this way, you need to amend your code to add HeaderManager [HashTree](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jorphan/collections/HashTree.html) to HTTPSamplerProxy HashTree. After that you need to add this [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html) to Thread Group, something like:

```
HashTree httpRequestTree = new HashTree();
httpRequestTree.add(httpRequest, manager);

testPlanTree.add(testPlan);
HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
threadGroupHashTree.add(httpRequestTree);
```

---

Full code, just in case:

```
// JMeter Test Plan, basically JOrphan HashTree
HashTree testPlanTree = new HashTree();

// Create Header Manager
HeaderManager manager = new HeaderManager();
manager.add(new Header("Foo", "Joe"));
manager.setName(JMeterUtils.getResString("header_manager_title")); // $NON-NLS-1$
manager.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HeaderManager.class.getName());
manager.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HeaderPanel.class.getName());

// HTTP Sampler - open example.com
HTTPSamplerProxy httpRequest = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
httpRequest.setDomain("example.com");
httpRequest.setPort(80);
httpRequest.setPath("/");
httpRequest.setMethod("GET");
httpRequest.setName("Open example.com");
httpRequest.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
httpRequest.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());


// Loop Controller
LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
loopController.setLoops(1);
loopController.setFirst(true);
loopController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, LoopController.class.getName());
loopController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, LoopControlPanel.class.getName());
loopController.initialize();

// Thread Group
ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
threadGroup.setName("Example Thread Group");
threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ThreadGroup.class.getName());
threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ThreadGroupGui.class.getName());

// Test Plan
TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("Create JMeter Script From Java Code");
testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, TestPlan.class.getName());
testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestPlanGui.class.getName());
testPlan.setUserDefinedVariables((Arguments) new ArgumentsPanel().createTestElement());

// HTTP Request Sampler and Header Manager
HashTree httpRequestTree = new HashTree();
httpRequestTree.add(httpRequest, manager);

// Construct Test Plan from previously initialized elements
testPlanTree.add(testPlan);
HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
threadGroupHashTree.add(httpRequestTree);
```

Check out [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) for more information on building JMeter Test Plan programatically.